# Can't Extract Hyperlinks Using WebBrowser in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser

I'm having a problem when trying to extract hyperlinks from web document!

The approach I'm trying to use is shown below:

```
HtmlElementCollection ht = wb.Document.Links;

foreach (HtmlElement item in ht)
{
    if (item.GetAttribute("href").Contains("name"))
    {
        linkList.Add(item.GetAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

When executing this code I get error "Specified cast is not valid." I guess the problem is in the fact, that method executing this code is called on a separate thread than webbrowser. On the same thread  i have no problem calling the method.

Comment: "Specified cast is not valid" is unlikely to have anything to do with threading, unless your threading has messed things up very badly. It suggests there's something in `wb.Document.Links` which is not a `HtmlElement`.

Comment: BTW, which Web Browser control is this? The Silverlight version?

Comment: The same exact method run on main thread works just fine, while Thread navigate = new Thread(() => navigateTo(webBrowser1));
navigate.Start(); variant fails.

Comment: Strong Suggestion: avoid multithreading until you understand it better. Alternatively, try passing `wb.Document.Links` to this thread instead of allowing it to illegally access the web browser from another thread.

Comment: Where are you getting it?  LinkList.Add ?? PS links don't have to have an attribute called href, would be wise to check if it's null before you call.Contains

Comment: Seems to be similar problem. using Webbrowser control in threads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193084/webbrowser-control-throws-seemingly-random-nullreferenceexception/16208263#16208263

Comment: Indeed, the problem was caused by use of multiple threads. I try'd passing `wb.Document.Links` as argument, which didn't work, so the solution I found is placing the "link getting code" in separate method and invoking the method, on the main thread (where browser is running). `BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { getUsers(webBrowser1, linkList); }));`

Comment: @user2183935 then how about posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is placing the "link getting code" in separate method and invoking the method, on the main thread (where browser is running).

`BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { getUsers(webBrowser1, linkList); }));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
        HtmlElementCollection hc = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        for (int i = 0; i < hc.Count; i++)
        {
            if (hc[i].GetAttribute("href") == "name")
                listBox1.Items.Add(hc[i].InnerHtml);// Or InnerText
        }
```