# using webbrowser for multiple pages

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on a project.On my mssql server i have so many urls and i need to check if i can login or not. Here is my code so far:

```
        public List<WebBrowser> myBrowsers = new List<WebBrowser>();

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SiteeeID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue);
        string url = "select http,username,pass,userID,passID,butonID from AyrintiSite where username!=''";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(url, cn))
            {
                cn.Open();

                dt.Load(cm.ExecuteReader());

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowserDocumentCompleted;
            browser.Navigate(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            myBrowsers.Add(browser);
        }
    }
    private void webBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
            return;

        WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;

        browser.Document.GetElementById("KullaniciAdiTextBox").SetAttribute("value", "username");
        browser.Document.GetElementById("SifreTextBox").SetAttribute("value", "pass");
        browser.Document.GetElementById("SistemeGirImageButton").InvokeMember("click");
        browser.DocumentCompleted -= webBrowserDocumentCompleted;
        browser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowserDestroyOnCompletion;
    }
    private void webBrowserDestroyOnCompletion(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
            return;

        if (e.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("Login"))
        {
            //send e-mail
        }
        WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
        browser.Dispose();
        myBrowsers.Remove(browser);

    }
```

now i have 17 pages in my datatable. 10-12 of them can login correctly but the others can't and my program sending me an e-mail. I checked thousand times it's all okey on my database,all of them should login. Is there any mistakes on my code?

Comment: [This extension (*NavigateAsync*) method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16208263/932418) may help

Comment: Before Navigate() method call constructor : webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();

Comment: If you create a new WebBrowser, you will loose the cookies.

Comment: There is a problem in your approach because you don't wait for the Document Completed event in the loop. A solution is to do a Navigate() to the first Url instead of a loop. Then, in the DocumentCompleted event, do some job and Navigate() to next Url.

Comment: I uptaded my questions with your advice. Can you check again? @jdweng

Comment: Can you give me an example, how can i navigate to next url? @Graffito

Comment: Check the status and make sure you are getting DONE 200.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler may help.  I suspect you are getting a return other than done 200.  Some webpages have java scripts running after document complete.  Try adding a wait of 30 seconds after document complete before reading data to see if you get better results.

Answer (score 0):

**Navigating to next URL in the DocumentCompleted event**

Declare a pageIndex variable to keep the Index in dt.rows:

```
 int pageIndex=0 ;
```

Replace the loop on dt.rows by the following:

```
        WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
        browser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowserDocumentCompleted;
        browser.Navigate(dt.Rows[pageIndex][0].ToString());
```

"Loop" on dt.rows in the DocumentCompleted event:

```
private void webBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath) return;
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    browser.Document.GetElementById( "KullaniciAdiTextBox").SetAttribute("value", "username");
    browser.Document.GetElementById( "SifreTextBox").SetAttribute("value", "pass");
    browser.Document.GetElementById( "SistemeGirImageButton").InvokeMember("click");
    pageIndex++ ;
    If (pageIndex<dt.Rows.Count) browser.Navigate(dt.Rows[pageIndex][0].ToString());
  }
```

Comment: thank you but i can not take the values from datatable in DocumentCompleted event. How can i do that?

Comment: Declare "DataTable dt" as a form variable like "myBrowsers" (*and don't redeclare it in your button click procedure*).