# Why is my code working using a MessageBox.Show() inside the code and it doesn't work without it?

Tags: c#

I want to save the web page source code and I have the following code:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
int SleepTime = 5000;
loadPage: browser.Navigate("https://google.com");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(SleepTime);
MessageBox.Show("browser.Navigae OK");
if(browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    string path = @"htmlCode.txt";
    if(browser.Document.Body.Parent.InnerText != null)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, browser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(browser.Document.Encoding));
        MessageBox.Show("Success! htmlCode.txt created");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("browser.Document.Body.Parent.InnerText=" + browser.Document.Body.Parent.InnerText);
        MessageBox.Show("Failure htmlCode.txt not created");
    }
}
```

if I comment

> MessageBox.Show("browser.Navigate OK");

my code it is not working... why?

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957182/load-url-from-txt-file-and-load-the-url-in-browser-synchronous-webclient-httpreq

Comment: @KadarBarna Click on the link in Eser's comment. Use that answer.

Comment: @JLRishe your words fall on deaf ears, I've found it's easier to just fix it myself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193084/webbrowser-control-throws-seemingly-random-nullreferenceexception

Comment: @EdPlunkett WebBrowser is **STA** and works in the current thread context. So Thread.Sleep(anynumber) would just block the UI and WebBrowser. What makes the code work is the MessageBox...

Answer (score -1):

Why is it not working?

Typical [Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Navigation takes time to finish. Your `MessageBox.Show` acts like a huge delay buffer which gives web browser enough time to finish the operation.

You should be using [DocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event to ensure this does not happen.

Comment: **1-** *Race condition* is commonly used when threads are involved. In OP's case, there is a single thread (UI thread). **2-** *DocumentCompleted* is the correct event. Navigated doesn't guarantee that the page is ready to use DOM objects

Comment: @L.B there is UI thread + webbrowser background thread. UI thread enters processing stage before background thread completes. I do think its considered a race condition. Updated the document completed part.

Comment: There is **no**  *webbrowser background thread*. WB control works in UI thread. If you block the UI thread (like Thread.Sleep), WB is also blocked.